# I have a problem understanding an article's line

Tags: reflexive-pronouns

Thank you always for your assistance.

My question is, [about a line in this article.](http://www.newsweek.com/michael-rubin-trump-teams-first-ethics-scandal-521622)

At the 7th line, it is saying,

> Gülen is a onetime ally of Erdogan’s whose exile and perhaps execution the Turkish president now demands.

I am sorry I am not able to understand particularly here.

> Gülen is a onetime ally of Erdogan’s whose exile and perhaps execution

Especially here

> Gülen is a onetime ally of Erdogan’s whose exile

Could someone explain to me kindly?

Thank you for you assistance in advance(m_m)

Comment: I would add a comma after "Erdogan’s": "Gülen is a onetime ally of Erdogan’s, whose exile and perhaps execution the Turkish president now demands." Probably "Erdogan" or "Gülen is a onetime *Erdogan* ally," might have been easier to understand.

Comment: @KentaroTomono Do you understand what _whose_ means? Have you studied _pronouns_ in English?

Comment: Yes,but it seems very confusing. Thanks to your comment, I think I somehow understood. So the Turkish president is **now** demanding the persecution of Gülen, but he was once an one time **ally**........

Comment: The possessive pronoun _whose_ refers to Gulen. You could rephrase the sentence as: _"Erdogan now demands the exile and perhaps execution of Gulen, who is a onetime ally of the Turkish president."_ (With regard to his already being in exile, the entire piece is badly written. It's journalism. You should not expect it to be well written.)

Comment: Thanks to P.E.Dant, this question is solved. Unless there is no answer, I will delete this question within 12 hours. Thank you for your all's assistance.

Comment: **Why I think this is a -- bad writing --** is because, the writer is saying 2 unprocessable things **One is exile, the other is execution**. You can not have someone exiled and at the same time **execute**.

Comment: One can _demand_ both exile and execution at the same time. This is different than _doing_ both at the same time.

Comment: Technically speaking, I think it would be Yes. **But Gulen is already in America**. It would be something like assassination, I think. Anyway, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to understanding this badly written sentence is in determing the antecedent of the possessive pronoun *whose.*

As presented, the sentence is:

> Gülen is a onetime ally of Erdogan’s whose exile and perhaps execution the Turkish president now demands.

The subject of this sentence is *Gülen,* and the verb in the main clause is the copula *is.* The main clause is:

> Gülen is a onetime ally of Erdogan's

The possessive pronoun *whose* introduces a *dependent clause:*

> *whose* exile and perhaps execution the Turkish president now demands.

Although it is possible to take from this confusing construction the impression that *Erdogan* is the antecedent of *whose,* it is *Gülen* to which it refers instead. A less confusing rendering of the same sentence is:

> Erdogan now demands the exile and perhaps execution of Gülen, who is a onetime ally of the Turkish president.